# Command to copy a file to another directory

Tags: windows, command, command-prompt

Please have a look at the following commands and what was the error in syntax? i wanted to copy the dll file to my project bin directory

```
C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f1
1d50a3a>dir /s /b /o:gn

C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f1
1d50a3a\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll

C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f1
1d50a3a>copy Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll C:\Documents and Settings\mural
i.madhava\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Rdclrender\Rdclrender\bin

The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Comment: You have a solution, I just wanted to add that you can enclose all filenames and paths in double quotes, even short names.  That makes it easy to remember - if you always use double quotes then it will work.  This also includes names like `cat&dog.txt` which is a short name but would fail without quotes because of the `&` character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply you need to place quotes around any path that has a space in it:

> copy Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll "C:\Documents and Settings\murali.madhava\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Rdclrender\Rdclrender\bin"

Answer (score 1):

If you have spaces in your paths (such as `C:\Documents and Settings`), you'll need to surround them with quotes to stop them being treated as multiple arguments:

```
copy blah.WinForms.dll "C:\Documents and Settings\blah\bin"
```

This gives you the three-argument command:

- `copy`
- `blah.WinForms.dll`
- `C:\Documents and Settings\blah\bin`

*Without* the quotes, you get the five-argument command which is *not* what you want:

- `copy`
- `blah.WinForms.dll`
- `C:\Documents`
- `and`
- `Settings\blah\bin`